# Is there a DSL or declarative system for TPL Dataflow?

Tags: task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Is there any DSL or other fully- or partially-declarative mechanism for declaring TPL Dataflow flows?  Or is the best (only) practice to just wire them up in code?

Failing that, is there any DSL or other fully- or partially-declarative mechanism for using *any* dataflow library that I could use as a model and/or source of ideas?

(I've searched without success so maybe one doesn't exist ... or maybe I didn't find it.)

**Update:** To answer @svick below as to why I want this and what do I gain by it:

First, I just like a sparser syntax that more clearly shows the flow rather than the details.  I think

```
downloadString => createWordList => filterWordList => findPalindromes;
```

is preferable to

```
downloadString.LinkTo(createWordList);
createWordList.LinkTo(filterWordList);
filterWordList.LinkTo(findPalindromes);
findPalindromes.LinkTo(printPalindrome);
```

with its repeated names and extra punctuation.  Similar to the way you'd rather use the [dot DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29#A_simple_example) to describe a DAG than a bunch of calls to the Visio DOM API. You can imagine a syntax for network flows, as well as pipelines, such that network flows in particular would be very clear. That may not seem compelling, of course, but I like it.

Second, I think that with a DSL you might be able to persist the DSL description, e.g., as a field in a row in a database, and then instantiate it later.  Though perhaps that's a different capability entirely.

Comment: [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/gg577609.aspx) might be a better fit if you're looking for a more declarative approach. Its functionality somewhat overlaps with TPL Dataflow, and many problems can be elegantly solved in either of the two frameworks.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing like that specifically for TDF, at least not anything official. Why do you feel a more declarative approach would make sense? What are the problems with the normal way of creating flows? What do you expect to gain?

Comment: @Svick It might relate to the fact this came inspired from Axum, which had syntax for declaring flow between "blocks". One possible gain is more expressive code through terse declaration I suppose.

Comment: You don't want this. You shouldn't link up pipelines like that. You don't need dataflow for pipelines. Just call one function after the other (`var a = A(); var b = B(a); ...`). You describe a logical data pipeline, but it does not have to be a physical data pipeline.

Comment: @usr - Thanks for telling me what I don't want.  I believe you've misunderstood the context.  We're talking TPL dataflow here, where each pipeline block gets to be executed asynchronously, with buffering between stages, with user-selectable parallelism, and other features.  Also, I explicitly mentioned network flow as well as pipelines.

Comment: In your DSL example you use none of these features. As soon as you use them the terse DSL syntax goes out of the window anyway.; You can asynchronously execute the pipeline stages without Dataflow using async/await. In your example, Dataflow adds nothing.

Comment: @usr - Ok, I accept that response. Don't get hung up on the example.  As it happens I copied it straight from an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604(v=vs.110).aspx) on TPL Dataflow.  It is, like many examples, a simplified version of the real thing.  DSL syntax can still be helpful - for example, the dot language (which I linked above) allows a terse syntax for the common case and yet simple attribute declarations for optional situations.  Many DSLs are like that.  I believe "out the window" is too strong a statement.

Comment: You might be right. I'll be monitoring this question for answers because I have none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the relevant facts and work from there:

1. There isn't anything like this for TPL Dataflow yet.
2. There isn't a good way of embedding a DSL into C#. The common compilers are not extensible and it would be hard to access local variables from a string-based DSL.
3. The are several limitations to operators in C#, but the most significant here is that operators can't be generic. This means that the sparser syntax either wouldn't be type-safe (which is unacceptable to me), or it can't use overloaded operators.
4. The `IDisposable` returned from `LinkTo()` that can be used to break the created link isn't used that often, so it doesn't have to be supported. (Or maybe the expression that sets up the flow could return a single `IDisposable` that breaks the whole flow?)

Because of this, I think the best that can be done is something like:

```cs
downloadString.Link(createWordList).Link(filterWordList).Link(findPalindromes);
```

This avoids the repetition of `LinkTo()`, but is not much better.

The implementation of the simple form of this is mostly trivial:

```cs
public static class DataflowLinkExtensions
{
    public static ISourceBlock<TTarget> Link<TSource, TTarget>(
        this ISourceBlock<TSource> source,
        IPropagatorBlock<TSource, TTarget> target)
    {
        source.LinkTo(
            target,
            new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        return target;
    }

    public static void Link<TSource>(
        this ISourceBlock<TSource> source, ITargetBlock<TSource> target)
    {
        source.LinkTo(
            target,
            new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }
}
```

I chose to set `PropagateCompletion` to `true`, because I think that makes the most sense here. But it could also be an option of `Link()`.

---

I think most of the alternative linking operators of Axum are not relevant to TPL Dataflow, but linking multiple blocks to or from the same block could be done by taking a collection or array as one of the parameters of `Link()`:

```cs
new[] { source1, source2 }.Link(target);
source.Link(target1, target2);
```

If `Link()` actually returned something that represents the whole flow (similar to [`Encapsulate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194718)), you could combine this to create more complicated flows, like:

```cs
source.Link(propagator1.Link(target1), target2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this analysis, esp. points 2 and 3 - point 3 is the killer isn't it?  I constantly forget that C# isn't as good as C++ w.r.t. operator overloading, and C++ isn't that great.  Why oh why can't we have in C# and C++ user-defined operator symbols?  Answer (I believe): Lack of imagination of language designers who, following the C example, believed a fixed set of operators must be terminals in the language and operator precedence needed to be defined via grammar rules.

Comment: @davidbak I think there are two reasons for that: 1. Custom operators simply aren't that common in “conventional programming” circles (only functional programmers and mathematicians use them). 2. Code using custom operators is harder to read: you need to read the documentation to figure out what exactly does `&>-` mean, but `LinkTo()` is mostly self-explanatory.

Comment: yes, I know those points (and thanks for your answer and comment) but isn't your point 1 ('aren't that common') just circular reasoning in a sense?  I mean, if we had 'em, they'd become popular.  Overloading operators got a bad smell associated with it (in C++)because when all you had were + - * / and a few others all your DSLs looked like arithmetic expressions, even when it was confusing.  And in this day of IDEs with Intellisense (or non-trademarked equivalents) the "what exactly does <=?-{ do" issue isn't as convincing as it used to be.  (Actually, I _am_ a functional programmer.)